# Add taxonomy terms into submenu

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, routes

I'm currently using drupal 7. I want to create an album gallery with different category. I wish to put "Albums" in the main menu, with the categories as sub menu under "Albums".

I had created a content type "Album", and plan to use taxonomy to creating vocabulary and terms as category.

However, I wish to make it automated. Once I create a album category, it will automatically appear in the sub menu under "albums". And each category will link to the list of albums under the category.

Anyone knows how to achieve the effect?

Comment: is your album path like `taxonomy/term/xx` or you used views and another path for album pages?

Comment: I'm using the normal node. For example, "album 1" and "album 2" is in category 1. The path for album 1 is xxx.com/node/1. Path for the list of albums under catergoty 1  is taxonomy/term/1. I want to add taxonomy/term/XX under the main menu "album".

Comment: its seams you look for http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu

Comment: Is it add in another menu block? Can I put it in the list of primary menu?

Comment: You can append your taxonomy menu anywhere in the menu hierarchy.  (So, yes, you can put it in the primary menu).

Answer (score 2):

For an action that is caused by an event I would use the [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Create new rule

Set rule name, etc.

Set event to act on - saving new term

Set a condition - term is in vocabulary album

Set action - add menu item

These options may not all appear with just Rules.  You may need additional rules modules to get some of these events, conditions, or actions to be available (I think there is one for menus and one for taxonomy, but they may be built in to rules i can't remember.).

Take what I said as a starting point to put you in the right direction.  Definitely sounds like what you want can be done with Rules.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to read through this module, and apply it on my work!

Comment: @vences No problem.  Let me know if you need help configuring.

Answer (score 1):

it seams you need custom module, try rebuild menu on taxonomy term CRUD operations,

create new module and implement this hooks:

- [hook_taxonomy_term_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_insert/7)
- [hook_taxonomy_term_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_update/7)
- [hook_taxonomy_term_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_delete/7)

Comment: I see. Any documentation as a guide line for me to refer?